# Loop over files to check if param is present, if not, add it with default value

Tags: ansible

For deployment process i have to go through a list of configuration files, and for each i have to check the presence of parameters, and if they are not present add them to the file

It's not just replacing the line by a default line with lineinfile, the parameters can be modified by hands and in this case i must do not change it by a default value and keep the actual.

In my role/defaults/main.yml i had created a list of files with params and default values to check

example :

```
webui_test_conf_files:
  - file: '{{ common_pms_workspace_path }}conf\conf-PROD.properties'
    param: 'printing.timeout'
    value: '{{ webui_template_configuration_vars.confPRODpropertiesj2.printing_timeout }}'
  - file: '{{ common_pms_workspace_path }}conf\conf-PROD.properties'
    param: 'period.bom.check'
    value: '{{ webui_template_configuration_vars.confPRODpropertiesj2.period_bom_check }}'
  - file: '{{ common_pms_workspace_path }}conf\conf-PROD.properties'
    param: 'enabled.bom.check'
    value: '{{ webui_template_configuration_vars.confPRODpropertiesj2.enabled_bom_check }}'
  - file: '{{ common_pms_workspace_path }}conf\sso-conf.properties'
    param: 'user.redirect.url'
    value: '{{ webui_template_configuration_vars.ssoconfpropertiesj2.user_redirect_url }}'
  - file: '{{ common_pms_workspace_path }}conf\sso-conf.properties'
    param: 'authorization.endpoint'
    value: '{{ webui_template_configuration_vars.ssoconfpropertiesj2.authorization_endpoint }}'
  - file: '{{ common_pms_workspace_path }}conf\sso-conf.properties'
    param: 'token.endpoint'
    value: '{{ webui_template_configuration_vars.ssoconfpropertiesj2.token_endpoint }}'
```

For every file (two in this example) i have to test the presence of each param.
if there is no occurence of this param, then add line in the file with : param=value
but if i found the param, i must do nothing for this one :-)

For now i can test and register the test like this

```
 - name: "Testing parameters"
   lineinfile:
     path: "{{ item.file }}"
     line: "{{ item.param }}"
     state: present
   check_mode: yes
   register: params
   loop: '{{ webui_test_conf_files }}'
```

But i do not succeed to use this registered value to do another loop :-(

Can you help me ?

Thanks a lot for your help !

Comment: `But i do not succeed to use this registered value to do another loop` => what is the exact problem you are facing? How did you try exactly? What is the error you get? How does the actual result differs from the expected one? Is it simply a problem using the registered results or the result itself which does not contain what you expect? Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/68271414/edit) your question to add more details about your implementation.

Comment: Sorry, in fact i do not find how to do this second loop...

for me i need to loop over each file a second time and update the file if params.rc != 0

Comment: Did you debug `params.results` to have a look at what it contains exactly? => all the results from the previous looped task in a list, each of them containing info about the task as well as an `item` entry with the original data that was used inside the loop. If you loop over `params.results`, `item.whatever` contains your task data (replace with an actual var from the task), and `item.item` the initial data.

Comment: item.item ! i do not know this one :)
thanks i will try this right now ^^

Comment: Without knowing, you just have to observe the data => `- debug: var=params`

Comment: Thanks for the tip, i didn't think to simply use debug .... my bad :-(

Comment: Regarding the `results` entry when registering a variable with a loop, read this: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_loops.html#registering-variables-with-a-loop

Comment: Please do not add large portions of code in comments, they are not made for this. [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/68271414/edit).

Answer (score 0):

Success with this code for windows test :-)

```
 - name: "Test parameters"
   win_shell: (Select-String -Path "{{ item.file }}" -Pattern "{{ item.param }}=")
   register: params
   check_mode: no
   ignore_errors: yes
   changed_when: no
   loop: '{{ webui_test_conf_files }}'

 - name: "Add missing parameters"
   win_lineinfile:
     path: "{{ item.item.file }}"
     line: "{{ item.item.param }}={{ item.item.value }}"
     state: present
   when: item.stdout | length == 0
   loop: "{{ params.results }}"
```

Thank you @Zeitounator for putting me on track !